# Coset Multiplication Proof

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup. Show that the sets
$(g_1H)(g_2H)=\{k_1k_2:k_1\in g_1H, k_2\in g_2H\}=\{g_1h_1g_2h_2:
h_1,h_2\in H\}$ and $(g_1g_2)H$ are equal.

Is this just the same thing as saying that coset multiplcation is well defined or is it different?

Comment: For coset multiplication to be well-defined, $(g_1H)(g_2H)=(g_3H)$ for some $g_3$, not necessarily for $g_3=g_1g_2$.

Answer (score 1):

An element $x$ in $(g_1H)(g_2H)$ is of the form $x=(g_1h)(g_2h')$ (with $h$ and $h'$ in $H$). Now we can rewrite as:
$$x=g_1hg_2h'=g_1g_2(g_2^{-1}hg_2)h'$$
Since $H$ is normal, $g_2^{-1}hg_2\in H$. Hence $(g_2^{-1}hg_2)h'\in H$ (since it is a subgroup), so $x=g_1g_2h''$ for some $h''\in H$. So $x\in g_1g_2H$. Hence $(g_1H)(g_2H)\subseteq g_1g_2H$.

The reverse inclusion is easier:

Let $x\in g_1g_2H$. Then $x=g_1g_2h$ for some $h\in H$. Now $x=(g_1e)(g_2h)$ ($e$ is the identity in $H$). So $x\in (g_1H)(g_2H)$. Hence $g_1g_2H\subseteq(g_1H)(g_2H)$, completing the proof.

It shows that the set of all left cosets of $H$ forms a group under the (most natural) multiplication of subsets $XY:=\{xy\mid x\in X,\; y\in Y\}$.